# PyGTK checkbutton's label on the left side

Tags: python, checkbox, gtk, pygtk

Is it possible to set the label for PyGTK's checkbutton on the left side instead of the default right side as the example below ?

```
Apple:  [x]
Orange: [ ]
Pear:   [x]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You could do it by creating a new class that inherits from `gtk.CheckButton`, but then the checkboxes wouldn't be lined up like in your example.

I would suggest making your check buttons with blank labels, and then adding separate `gtk.Label`s to label them. Line them up in a `gtk.Table` or `gtk.Grid`.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the only way out is assigning a label to be placed on the left side of the checkbox is the only way out. I am using VBox and HBox to orientate them and they are worling pretty nicely.

Comment: @thotheolh I'm curious: How did you make them line up by using two different orientations of `Box`? I'm having trouble imagining how that could work, at least without a `SizeGroup` to force alignment. Anyway, a `Grid` is the correct way to orient things in both dimensions, and it seems like exactly what's needed here.

Answer (score 1):

I got the opposite problem, my labels are set to the left by default (maybe because my default language is right to left)

Comment: What language and charset did you enable on your system ?

Comment: export language = he_IL (hebrew)

Comment: It's probably language and charset related.

Comment: Yes, as per the subsequent answer by Gsus, this is because the internal container of the CheckButton obeys text direction when arranging its children. This is not really an answer, although I guess it recovers half a point for _hinting_ at one possible answer, which Gsus posted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the same problem and the solution was to set the widget text direction from the right to the left.

It worked in gtk#.

Comment: This kind of makes sense, but equally it is rather hacky, and I wonder whether it comes with any unexpected/unwanted side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

In modern GTK (3.20 or better, maybe working on previous versions too) this can be easily accomplished directly in the CSS by using negative margins, e.g.:

```css
checkbutton {
    /* Give enough space on the left to accomodate the label */
    margin-left: 200px;
}
checkbutton label {
    /* 50 extra pixels for spacing and for the indicator width */
    margin-left: -250px;
}
```